# Tex tabularx keeps displaying narrow cells

Tags: latex

I'm using tabularx macTex to draw a table like of a shape like a reversed stage.

I'm using my code as follows:

```
\begin{table}[h]
\renewcommand\arraystretch{1.5}
\centering
\begin{tabularx}{150mm}{YYYYYYYYYY}
\cline{1-10}
\multicolumn{1}{|Y}{} & \multicolumn{1}{|Y}{} & \multicolumn{1}{|Y}{} & \multicolumn{1}{|Y}{} & \multicolumn{1}{|Y}{} & \multicolumn{1}{|Y}{} & \multicolumn{1}{|Y}{} & \multicolumn{1}{|Y}{} & \multicolumn{1}{|Y}{} & \multicolumn{1}{|Y|}{}
\\ \cline{1-10}
I/N & \multicolumn{1}{|Y}{} & \multicolumn{1}{|Y}{} & \multicolumn{1}{|Y}{} & \multicolumn{1}{|Y}{} & \multicolumn{1}{|Y}{} & \multicolumn{1}{|Y}{} & \multicolumn{1}{|Y}{} & \multicolumn{1}{|Y}{} & \multicolumn{1}{|Y|}{}
\\ \cline{2-10}
& forgot/V & \multicolumn{1}{|Y}{} & \multicolumn{1}{|Y}{} & \multicolumn{1}{|Y}{} & \multicolumn{1}{|Y}{} & \multicolumn{1}{|Y}{} & \multicolumn{1}{|Y}{} & \multicolumn{1}{|Y}{} & \multicolumn{1}{|Y|}{}
\\ \cline{3-10}
&& a &&&&&&&
\\ \cline{4-10}
&&& bag/N &&&&&&
\\ \cline{5-10}
&&&& of &&&&&
\\ \cline{6-10}
&&&&& rackets/N &&&&
\\ \cline{7-10}
&&&&&& which &&&
\\ \cline{8-10}
&&&&&&& I/N &&
\\ \cline{9-10}
&&&&&&&& bought/V &
\\ \cline{10-10}
&&&&&&&&& yesterday/Adv \\

\end{tabularx}
\caption{Parsing pattern I of sentense \ref{st:rel2} .}
\end{table}
```

it looks like in figure 1

[image: figure1]

but when I add one more \multicolumn{1}{|Y}{} in the 4th row it turns to be like this:

[image: figure2]

Anyone knows how to fix this？

PS：there's an error message saying :

> Underfull \hbox (badness 10000)

Answer (score 0):

You can define table as follows prior to \begin{document}:

`\newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{#1}}
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{#1}}
\newcolumntype{R}[1]{>{\raggedleft\arraybackslash}p{#1}}
\setlength\extrarowheight{10pt}`

Here, L, C, R refer to the text alignment within the table in each column i.e. Left, Center, Right respectively.

Then, when creating the table, specify distances as follows:

`\begin{tabular}{|C{1.6cm}|C{1.6cm}|C{1.6cm}|C{3cm}|C{3.1cm}|}`

You can use other units of measurement like inches (in). Check LaTex documentation.